# Proper way to include modules on gem classes to add methods to gem classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, module, initialization, rubygems, initializer

I am trying to load modules into some of the Mailboxer gem classes to add extra methods to those classes. Sometimes my attempts work however, I will usually get "Undefined method" error.

I have tried adding the modules to the lib directory and then issuing a load directive in the config/application.rb file like so:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Then using the initializers/mailboxer.rb file to include these into the respective classes.

I have also tried (inside the intitializer/mailboxer.rb file) writing class_eval statements on the classes themselves and adding the methods through the class_eval statements.

I am currently putting the modules inside the app/helpers directory and changing the module names to MailboxerMessagesHelper, MailboxerConversationsHelper, etc. and then using the initializer/mailboxer.rb file to include them like so:

```
Mailboxer::Message.include(MailboxerMessagesHelper)
```

All of these attempts work occasionally. I have seen answers to similar issues stating that this is a development environment issue since rails reloads between each request. However, I think the problem is I am doing this wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Found that one thing is for certain that is causing this issue. It appears that modifying the module files in any way will cause the application not to see the module at all until reloading the server.

I have also created a directory in the helpers directory named after the Mailboxer which I think is convention. I then added the module inside the directory and used naming convention like: Mailboxer::ConversationsHelper instead. Seems to work so far.